# need to write compare point method in my class called point . ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, compare, points

hi i have wrttien this points class in ruby but i need a compare method class to anybody any ideas where to start?

```
class Point 
  attr_reader :x, :y

  def initialize x,y
    @x = x
    @y = y
  end

  def addpoint(x,y)   # used to add points 
    Point.new(@x+x, @y+y)
  end

  def to_s
    x.to_s+" , "+y.to_s # used to change from object to strings
  end
end
```

Comment: what do you want to compare to what? `Point` instance to `Point` instance? and the result should be true, if the `x` and `y` of both points are equal?

Comment: yes sorry i forgot to state this in the question

Answer (score 1):

```
class Point
  def == p
     return false unless p.kind_of? Point
     x == p.x and y == p.y
  end
end
```